# How can i find an element with a custom attribut that equals a specific value?

Tags: jquery, loops, custom-attributes, each

I am trying to use a .each loop to find specific elements in a list that when a custom attribute, "pid", is not equal to 0 i can perform an action. How can i go about finding each element? so far i have:

```
$.each($('.container ul li'),function() {
  var pid = $('.container ul li').attr('pid');
  $(this).remove().after($("container ul li[pid='"+pid+"']"));

  });
```

but this is not doing anything here. can anyone please help?

essentially what i am trying to do is take each element in the list and group them together by the attribute "pid", so i am searching the list for when the pid does not equal 0, then i need to search it again, and find its match, when each pid is equal to each other, (note: there will only be one match), and append it after the first, or the original.

Comment: Maybe you need `.container`? `container` will match the element `container`. Also note that `$('container ul li').attr('pid');` will always give you the `pid` of the first element that is matched by `container ul li`. Is this what you want? Please provide more details.

Comment: i just updated it, hopefully that makes a little more sense. thanks for helping btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find any `li` with a `pid` that is not `0` if that is what you want. It will then start to group the items by `pid`.

```
var groups = [];

$('.container ul li[pid][pid!="0"]').each(function(){
    var pid = this.getAttribute("pid");

    if(groups[pid]){
        groups[pid].push(this);
    }else{
        groups[pid] = [this];
    }
}
```

This code would produce a list of lists. You can access all of the items with a given `pid` by accessing `groups[pid]` so all of the items with `pid = 5` will be in `groups[5]`.

Comment: yeah i need to find any li where pid does not equal 0 but then i need to search that list again and find where the pid's match. does that make sense?